# Syntax for Google Calculator

Tags: google-calculator

I frequently use Google's ability to plot functions to get a quick view of what a function looks like, for example: [sin(x), x^3](http://www.google.com/search?q=sin(x),+x%5E3). However, some operators that work when given a number, like [3! * x](http://www.google.com/search?q=3!+*+x), which plots `6*x`, don't seem to work when applied to the `x` variable: [3! * x!](http://www.google.com/search?q=3!+*+x!) doesn't give a plot at all.

I have failed to use the factorial operator ([x!](http://www.google.com/search?q=x!)), and the modulus operator ([x mod 3](http://www.google.com/search?q=x+mod+3)).

Is there a reference, documentation or whatever specifying the syntax for Google Calculator?

I know it can do some pretty advanced things like plot functions in 3D over a specified range, but trying to use these features by hitting at random in the dark is kind of sub-optimal.

Comment: Why don't you use wolfram alpha?

Comment: @CyberDude because I have google as my search bar provider :), and because my (quite slow) computer tends to lag a lot with Wolfram Alpha, which makes frequent edition of the function a pain (when trying to get a specific shape, for example). When I need some more complex plots, I go to Wolfram Alpha, but I'd like to be able to use google for simple plots, without having to guess the syntax.

Comment: I'd also like for them to support modulus.  Wolfram Alpha won't let you zoom and pan around the plot without a "Pro" account.  I guess you get what you pay for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no documentation for what functions the Google Search Graphing Calculator can support (see *diatribe* for the why).

From what I have witnessed, the calculator can only graph three types of functions.

- Trigonometric
- Polynomial
- Absolute value

I have only tested the above in 2D space but I believe they also work and 3D spatial coordinates as well.

It seems Google looks to users to do some of their documentation for them. I don't think the Google Search Graphing Calculator even has an official website (just a [blog](http://insidesearch.blogspot.com/2011/12/showing-some-love-to-math-lovers.html)).

**Diatribe**
I have experienced this same issue on several occasions with Google products. The things Google focuses on are usually explained in a adequate manner, but for other less noticeable features there is little to no explanation at all. For example, the Google Voice service is able to store all of your conversations in an organized way but there is little documentation on how to organize historical phone calls/text/voice mails. I couldn't even find the *name* for the "conversation" or "historical record" or whatever it is these items are called (never did find an answer even after contacting Google directly).